# How to set up IRIS database with Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus, intersystems-iris

I'm trying to use Intersystems IRIS Database with
Quarkus, but I'm getting problems making it work
does anyone knows how to set up the Intersystems IRIS Database
on Quarkus ?

I did that on my pom.xml  and also I added the jar
hibernate-iris-1.0.0.jar and intersystems-jdbc-3.2.0.jar but it's not working

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.intersystems</groupId>
            <artifactId>intersystems-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/intersystems-jdbc-3.2.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-iris</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/hibernate-iris-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

This is my application.properties

`quarkus:
  datasource:
    db-kind: other 
    username: _system
    password: *****
    jdbc:
      url: jdbc:IRIS://localhost:1972/USER
      driver: com.intersystems.jdbc.IRISDriver
  hibernate-orm:
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.InterSystemsIRISDialect
    jdbc:
      timezone: UTC`

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, to set up Intersystems IRIS on Quarkus you need to add manually the jar file, and also you need to set up the pom.xml also some setup from Intersystems was made as a java class.  you can see the solution looking at my project on GitHub
this is the link: https://github.com/JoseAdemar/quarkus-project-with-intersystems-ris-database